# Set Time to GregorianCalendar

Tags: java, gregorian-calendar

I have a Task Scheduler who use GregorianCalendar,
I would like to set time like 09:30:00
Code:

```
   Calendar nextExecutionTime = new GregorianCalendar();
                Date lastActualExecutionTime = t.lastActualExecutionTime();
                nextExecutionTime.setTime(lastActualExecutionTime != null ? lastActualExecutionTime : new Date());

                nextExecutionTime.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 9);
                nextExecutionTime.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);
                nextExecutionTime.add(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
```

but when i get time from nextExecutionTime it's returned weird values:

```
Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY 19
Calendar.MINUTE 44
Calendar.SECOND 27
```

Comment: `nextExecutionTime.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 9);` - so is it about `10` o'clock now?

Comment: @ScaryWombat I do not understand

Comment: You are `adding` 9 hours and ending up with `19`

Comment: `add(...)` is very different than `set(...)`

Answer (score 1):

## Avoid legacy date-time classes

You are using terrible date-time classes that were supplanted years ago by the *java.time* classes.

## `Instant`

Record your last run as an `Instant`, a moment in UTC.

## `LocalTime`

Specify your desired time of day.

```
LocalTime lt = LocalTime.of( 9 , 30 ) ;
```

## `LocalDate`

Get today’s date. This requires a time zone as the date varies around the globe by zone for any given moment.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Chicago" ) ;
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.now( z ) ;
```

## `ZonedDateTime`

Assemble those parts into a `ZonedDateTime` object, determining a moment, a specific point on the timeline.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.of( ld , lt , z ) ;
```

## Adjust to UTC

Extract a `Instant`, to adjust to UTC.

```
Instant instant = zdt.toInstant() ;
```

## Convert

If you need to use the legacy classes to interoperate with old code not yet updated to *java.time*, convert. Call new conversion methods added to the old classes. Look for `to…` and `from…` methods.

You can convert between [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) and [`GregorianCalendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html).

```
GregorianCalendar gc =  GregorianCalendar.from( zdt ) ;
```

Comment: agreed, but OP apparently needs a `GregorianCalendar` based on questions first sentence.... (maybe the task scheduler is also very old)

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger Thanks, fixed. I added a section at the bottom about converting.